# I got a task to store a stringofoctets i.e 0C001A0001000800030000010501000000800100001003103F002A0 into 0x000C, 0x001A ,0x0001, 0x0008 ,0x0100

Tags: networking, bit-manipulation, iot

I wrote a code for the same -

```
var string  = "0C001A0001000";
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(string.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char

  

   var hex = new Uint16Array(buf);
     
  for (var i =0, strLen=string.length; i < strLen; i++){
      
       hex[i] = (string[i] << (4*i) & 0XFF)
        hex[i+1]  =  (string[i+1] & 0XFF);
        
    
  }
  console.log((hex));
```

but the output is :
Uint16Array [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0 ] instead of hex digits .
I'm new in this field please provide the correct code for the same . The resulting hex digits should be in little endian form.

Comment: Please learn how to do proper indentation of code, it will help you later.

Answer (score 0):

Hex is basically a display format (you do not "store" ints as hex); the code below gets the ints and displays them as hex.

```
var string  = "0123456789AB"; // len needs to be N * 4 (fixed to 12; was 13)
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(string.length/2); // 4 chars for each 16bit #
var hex = new Uint16Array(buf)
     
for (var i=0, strLen=string.length; i < strLen; i+=4){
    hex[i/4] = 0

    hex[i/4] += (parseInt(string[i+0],16) << (4*1))
    hex[i/4] += (parseInt(string[i+1],16) << (4*0))
    hex[i/4] += (parseInt(string[i+2],16) << (4*3))
    hex[i/4] += (parseInt(string[i+3],16) << (4*2))
}

for (var i=0, strLen=string.length; i < strLen/4; i++){
    console.log("0x" + hex[i].toString(16))
}
```

Comment: What if user enter a string with spaces ? . plus if string is odd then ?